# sans serif math in tables and siunitx

Tags: fonts, math-mode, tables, siunitx, sans-serif

I want to know the easiest way to ensure that the content inside a tabular, including siunitx columns is set using a/the sans serif math font. The normal document is set in serif font.

This approach shows some of my attempts:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\makeatletter 
% dcolumn column
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{>{\DC@{.}{ ,}{#1}}l<{\DC@end}}
% sans serif d-column (from http://www.torsten-schuetze.de/tex/tabsatz-2004.pdf)
\newcolumntype{j}[1]{%
>{\DC@{.}{,}{#1}\mathsf\bgroup}l%
<{\egroup\DC@end}%
}
% sans serif column, including math
\newcolumntype{k}{%
>{$\mathsf\bgroup}l%
<{\egroup$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}%

% table with d-columns: fails to compile
\begin{tabular}{j{4.2}d{4.2}ll}
\hline
2.3456 & 2.3456 & 2.3456 & 2.3456 \\
34.2345 & 34.2345 & 34.2345 & 34.2345 \\
56.7835 & 56.7835 & 56.7835 & 56.7835 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\mbox{}\vspace{1em}\
% using siunitx commands instead
\sisetup{table-figures-integer = 2, table-figures-decimal = 4, math-rm=\mathsf}
\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{S
k
S[table-number-alignment = left]
S[table-number-alignment = right]}
\hline
{Some Values} & {Some Values} & {Some Values / \si{kg/m^2}} & {Some Values} \\
\hline
2.3456 & 2.3456 & 2.3456 & 2.3456 \\
{$\mathsf{a^2}$} & 34.2345 & 34.2345 & 34.2345 \\
56.7835 & 56.7835 & 56.7835 & 56.7835 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}%
```

The first tabular fails to compile. The second is set in sans serif except the `\si{}` command. However the code looks quite complicated. Appended is the result.

[image]

Comment: Not part of the question, but you could just use `table-format = 2.4` in place of `table-figures-integer = 2, table-figures-decimal = 4`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `siunitx`, there are a couple of potential approaches. First, as Stefan has said you can detect the current font:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs,lmodern,siunitx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcolumntype{k}{%
>{$\mathsf\bgroup}l%
<{\egroup$}%
}


\begin{document}
\sffamily

\begin{center}
  \sisetup{table-format = 2.4,detect-family}
  \begin{tabular}{S
  k
  S[table-number-alignment = left]
  S[table-number-alignment = right]}
  \toprule
  {Some Values} & {Some Values} & {Some Values / \si{kg/m^2}} & {Some Values} \\
  \midrule
  2.3456 & 2.3456 & 2.3456 & 2.3456 \\
  {$\mathsf{a^2}$} & 34.2345 & 34.2345 & 34.2345 \\
  56.7835 & 56.7835 & 56.7835 & 56.7835 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The second approach is to set the font used by `siunitx` for both text and math mode material to be sanserif

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs,lmodern,siunitx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcolumntype{k}{%
>{$\mathsf\bgroup}l%
<{\egroup$}%
}


\begin{document}
\sffamily

\begin{center}
  \sisetup{table-format = 2.4, math-rm=\mathsf, text-rm=\sffamily}
  \begin{tabular}{S
  k
  S[table-number-alignment = left]
  S[table-number-alignment = right]}
  \toprule
  {Some Values} & {Some Values} & {Some Values / \si{kg/m^2}} & {Some Values} \\
  \midrule
  2.3456 & 2.3456 & 2.3456 & 2.3456 \\
  {$\mathsf{a^2}$} & 34.2345 & 34.2345 & 34.2345 \\
  56.7835 & 56.7835 & 56.7835 & 56.7835 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

In both cases, I've used `table-format = 2.4` as a shortcut to set up the reserved space. This is often easier than doing things piece by piece.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am working on a talk for students and this version is what I am going to present. The complete lecture will be available next week.

Comment: The decimal separator is not set to sans-serif. Visible e.g. with `locale=DE`. How can I get that corrected?

Comment: I found it myself: `\sisetup{detect-family, mode=text}`

Answer (score 7):

If you specify the option `detect-family` for `siunitx`, the package would be able to detect that the units are used in sans-serif mode.

```
\usepackage[detect-family]{siunitx}
```

You could use the `sansmath` package for switching to sans-serif math:

```
\usepackage{sansmath}
\newcolumntype{k}{>{\sansmath$}l<{$\unsansmath}}
```

Use `\sansmath` and `\unsansmath` outside math mode, so with `dcolumn` before `\DC@` and after `\DC@end`, respectively:

```
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{>{\sansmath\DC@{.}{ ,}{#1}}l<{\DC@end\unsansmath}}
```

Comment: Alternatively, for `siunitx` you'd set both `math-rm = \mathsf` and `text-rm = \sffamily`. [I'd nearly got an answer read for that plus `detect-family` :-)]

Comment: @Stefan Kottwitz: As far as I understand the sansmath package works only with a few font packages. I for example am using charter and the math version, together with frutiger as a sans font. Also I do not really want to use the dcolumn package.
@JosephWright: setting `math-rm` and `text-rm`seems to work.

Comment: @JosephWright: You could write an answer which Matthias could accept.

Comment: This is a case where I think `\sansmath\(` and `\)\unsansmath` are better than using `$` since then it's clear what's inside and what's outside mathmode…

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Done

Comment: @JosephWright: there seems to be a bug in siunitx, when converting . to ,: `\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}`. The comma is taken from the roman font, not the sans font.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech This may be due to the choice of font. For example, `$\mathsf{,}$` in a standard Computers Modern set up does not really look that sanserif to me, and I'd go for `\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {\text{,}}}`.